# Changing the marker on the same set of data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of data that comes from two different sources, and I have multiple sets graphed together. So essentially 6 scatterplots with error bars (all different colors), and each scatterplot has two sources.

Basically I want the blue scatterplot to have two different markers, `'o' and's'`. I currently have done this by plotting each point individually with a loop and checking to see if the source is 1 or 2. If it is 1 it plots a `'s'` if the source is 2 then it plots a `'o'`.

However this method does not really allow for having a legend. (Data1, Data2,...Data6)

Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:

I want a cleaner method for this, something along the lines of

`x=[1,2,3]`

`y=[4,5,6]`

`m=['o','s','^']`

`plt.scatter(x,y,marker=m)`

But this returns an error Unrecognized marker style

Comment: This can not be done with a single scatter call, you must loop over the marker shapes.  The way that scatter is implemented under the covers it can only use one marker shape (which it the scales and colors as needed) per call to scatter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These were all alright, but not really what I was looking for. The problem was how I parsed through my data and how I could add a legend in the wouldn't mess that up. Since I did a for-loop and plotted each point individually based on if it was measured at Observation location 1 or 2 whenever I made a legend it would plot over 50 legend entries. So I plotted my data as full sets (Invisibly and with no change in symbols) then again in color with the varying symbols. This worked better. Thanks though

Answer (score 3):

A more pythonic way (but still a loop) might be something like

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
l=['data1','data2','data3']
m=['ob','sb','^b']
f,a = plt.subplots(1,1)
[a.plot(*data, label=lab) for data,lab in zip(zip(x,y,m),l)]
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.xlim(0,4)
plt.ylim(3,7);
```

[image]

But I guess this is not the most efficient way if you have lots of datapoints.

If you want to use `scatter` try something like

```
m=['o','s','^']
f,a = plt.subplots(1,1)
[a.scatter(*data, marker=m1, label=l1) for data,m1,l1 in zip(zip(x,y),m,l)]
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure, there is also a possibility to apply `**` and dicts here.

**UPDATE:**
Instead of looping over the plot command the ability of matplotlib's plot function to read an arbitrary number of x,y,fmt groups, see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot).

```
x=np.random.random((3,6))
y=np.random.random((3,6))
l=['data1','data2','data3']
m=['ob','sb','^b']
plt.plot(*[i[j] for i in zip(x,y,m) for j in range(3)])
plt.legend(l,loc='lower right')
```

Comment: As a comment, `plot` is always faster than `scatter`.  If all of your marks will be the same size and color, use `plot`.  Only use `scatter` if you need to continuously change the marker size or color.

Answer (score 2):

Calling plot in a loop is fine.  You just need to keep the list of lines returned by plot and use fig.legend to create a legend for the whole figure.  See http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html

Comment: I would like a more pythonic, cleaner way of doing it. Is there a way of mapping the markers to a particular array?

For instance
`x=[1,2,3]`
`y=[4,5,6]`
`m=['o','s','^']`
`plt.scatter(x,y,marker=m])`

But this returns an error `Unrecognized marker style`

Comment: You can only have one marker per call.  You can plot multiple lines in one call, but they would all have the same marker.

Answer (score 2):

Seconded to @tcaswell 's comments, `.scatter()` returns `collections.PathCollection`, which provides a fast way of plotting a large number of identical shaped objects. You can use a loop to plot the data as many scatter plots (and many different datasets) but in my opinion it looses all the speed benefit provided by `.scatter()`.

With these being said, it is however not true that the dots have to be identical in a scatter plot. You can have different `linewidth`, `edgecolor` and many other things. But the dots have to be the same shape. See this example, assigning different colors (and only plot one dataset):

```
>>> sc=plt.scatter(x, y, label='test')
>>> sc.set_color(['r','g','b'])
>>> plt.legend()
```

See details in http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html.

[image]

Comment: you missed varying the size ;)